# tcl array question - key with quotes

Tags: arrays, tcl

this surprised me

```
>set foo("bar") 12
12
>parray foo
foo("bar") = 12
>set foo(bar) 12
12
>parray foo
foo("bar") = 12
foo(bar)   = 12
```

it seems that the literal foo is not the same as "foo". And yet

```
>string length foo
3
>string length "foo"
3
```

what am I failing to understand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `"` character is only special to Tcl's parser at the start of a word (or the end of a word that was started by `"`, of course). In fact, if you'd put spaces in you would have got an error:

```
% set foo("b a r") 2
wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
```

In the case where you're doing the `string length` calls, the `"` *is* at the start of a word so it is special. If we put an extra leading junk character, we see that the specialness of `"` goes away:

```
% string length x"bar"
6
```

If you're doing something complicated with array indices, I think it's usually easier to put the name of the element in a variable itself, since then it's clearer what's going on (and usually easier to debug too):

```
set idx "bar"
set foo($idx) 12
```

Comment: ty - and there i was thinking that tcl wasnt as wierd as perl

Comment: As one? `{foo(b a r)}` (e.g., `${foo(b a r)}`) but it doesn't come up very often in my experience.

Comment: You can also do `set key "b a r"; puts $foo($key)`