# TCL array key is not being recognized

Tags: arrays, list, tcl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tcl array question - key with quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833306/tcl-array-question-key-with-quotes)

I have the following code:

```
set my_list1 {"a" "b"}
set my_list2 {"@1" "@2"}
array set  my_array {}

foreach li1 $my_list1 li2 $my_list2 {
    set my_array($li1) $li2
}

puts $my_array("a")
```

On the list line I get ERROR "can't read my_array("a"): no such element in array"

Why?

I have it, because when I write

```
set newVar "a"
puts $my_array($newVar)
```

it returns the value!

Comment: very close to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833306/tcl-array-question-key-with-quotes

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same problem!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just one of those things in Tcl. The array element is not `my_array("a")` -- it's `my_array(a)`. Don't include the quotes when referencing the array. They're actually not necessary, although in that case note harmful, when you're installing the data into the array in the first place -- i.e.,

```
set my_list1 {a b}
```

would be just fine.

Tcl looks enough like a "normal" programming language that it's easy to forget how primitive its parser really is. Remember that everything is broken down into "words" by whitespace. If a double-quote character isn't preceded by whitespace, it isn't at the start of a word, and it no longer has any special significance. A reference to an array element is a single word, and after variable interpolation, it has to have *exactly* the right text. You can't put quote marks around the element name because simply those quote marks are not part of the correct text of that word.

Comment: I have changed my_array("a") -> my_array(a) and set my_list1 {"a" "b"} -> set my_list1 {a b} and it worked, but why it was not working formerly?

Comment: Even no need change  my_list1 {"a" "b"} -> set my_list1 {a b}. The my_array("a") -> my_array(a) is enough!

Comment: Using `parray my_list1` would have told you what was actually in the array. It's helpful for debugging.

Comment: Duuuh! `parray my_array` because you're printing the array, not the list…