# tcl array - error no such element found

Tags: arrays, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have created two tree control widgets and a scrollbar widget. And i have radiobuttons that lets the user to choose which widget to scroll based on the button selection. So i created the widgets as below :

```
package require Tk
package require treectrl

namespace eval ::at::GUI {
  variable Priv;
  variable OptionsRB;

  set Priv(treePrimary) "";
  set Priv(treeSecondary) "";
  set Priv(treeScrollbar) "";

  if { ![info exists OptionsRB] } { 
    set OptionsRB(optColor) "ColorOnDraw";
    set OptionsRB(optHighlight) "HighlightBold";

    set OptionsRB(matchColor) "NoColor";

    set OptionsRB(optSelHighlight) "";

    set OptionsRB(scrollTree) "LeftTree";
  }
}

proc ::at::GUI::DrawGUI {} {
  variable Priv;

  set frm_treeFrame [ttk::labelframe .treeFrame -text "Tree Area"];  

  set Priv(treePrimary) [treectrl $frm_treeFrame.treePrimary]
  set Priv(treeSecondary) [treectrl $frm_treeFrame.treeSecondary]

  set Priv(treeScrollbar) [ttk::scrollbar $frm_treeFrame.sb_treeScroll -command "::at::GUI::yview"]

  grid $Priv(treePrimary) $Priv(treeSecondary) $Priv(treeScrollbar) -sticky news;
  grid columnconfigure $frm_treeFrame 0 -weight 1;
  grid columnconfigure $frm_treeFrame 1 -weight 1;
  grid rowconfigure $frm_treeFrame 0 -weight 1;

  set frm_ST [ttk::labelframe .scrollTreeOptions -text "Scroll Option"];

  set rb_leftTree [ttk::radiobutton $frm_ST.rb1 -text "Left Tree" -variable [namespace current]::OptionsRB(scrollTree) -value LeftTree -command [namespace current]::configScroll ]
  set rb_rightTree [ttk::radiobutton $frm_ST.rb2 -text "Right Tree" -variable [namespace current]::OptionsRB(scrollTree) -value RightTree -command [namespace current]::configScroll ] 
  set rb_bothTree [ttk::radiobutton $frm_ST.rb3 -text "Both Tree" -variable [namespace current]::OptionsRB(scrollTree) -value BothTree -command [namespace current]::configScroll ] 

  grid $rb_leftTree -row 1 -padx {30 5} -pady 5 -sticky w
  grid $rb_rightTree -row 2 -padx {30 5} -pady 5 -sticky w
  grid $rb_bothTree -row 3 -padx {30 5} -pady 5 -sticky w

  # Grid all the frames in main window. 
  grid $frm_treeFrame -sticky news;
  grid $frm_ST -sticky news;

  ##############################
  ::at::GUI::CreateLemes $Priv(treePrimary)
  ::at::GUI::CreateLemes $Priv(treeSecondary)

  foreach tree [list $Priv(treePrimary) $Priv(treeSecondary)] {
    for {set i 0} {$i < 20} {incr i} {
      set parent [expr {int(rand()*$i)}]
      $tree item create -tag item$i -button auto
      $tree item lastchild $parent item$i
      $tree item text item$i name item$i
    }
  }
  return;  
}

proc ::at::GUI::CreateLemes {T} {
  $T element create rect rect -fill [list blue selected]
  $T element create name text

  set S [$T style create nameStyle]
  $T style elements $S {rect name};
  $T style layout $S rect -detach yes -iexpand xy;
  $T style layout $S name -detach no -iexpand xy -expand e;

  $T column create -tag name -itemstyle $S -text Items
  $T configure -treecolumn first;
}

proc ::at::GUI::configScroll {args}  {
  variable Priv;
  variable OptionsRB;

  if {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "LeftTree"} {
    $Priv(treePrimary) -yscrollcommand "::at::GUI::yset    $Priv(treeScrollbar)";
  } elseif {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "RightTree"} {
    $Priv(treeSecondary) -yscrollcommand "::at::GUI::yset $Priv(treeScrollbar)";
  } elseif {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "BothTree"} {
    $Priv(treePrimary) -yscrollcommand "::at::GUI::yset    $Priv(treeScrollbar)";
    $Priv(treeSecondary) -yscrollcommand "::at::GUI::yset $Priv(treeScrollbar)";
  }
}

proc ::at::GUI::yset {sb args}  {
  uplevel [linsert $args 0 $sb set]
  ::at::GUI::yview moveto [lindex [$sb get] 0]
}

proc ::at::GUI::yview {args}  {
  variable Priv;
  variable OptionsRB;

  parray OptionsRB;

  if {![info exists $OptionsRB(scrollTree)]} {
    puts "INFO DOESN'T EXIST.";
  }

  if {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "LeftTree"} {
    eval [linsert $args 0 $Priv(treePrimary) yview];
  } elseif {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "RightTree"} {
    eval [linsert $args 0 $Priv(treeSecondary) yview];
  } elseif {$OptionsRB(scrollTree) eq "BothTree"} {
    eval [linsert $args 0 $Priv(treePrimary) yview];
    eval [linsert $args 0 $Priv(treeSecondary) yview];
  }
}
```

So here in the procedure `::at::GUI::yview` i am getting an error saying that `can't read "OptionsRB(scrollTree)": no such element in array while executing 
"info exists $OptionsRB(scrollTree)" ...`. So i tried to print the array data using `parray OptionsRB;` and the result is

```
    OptionsRB(optColor) = ColorOnDraw
    OptionsRB(optHighlight) = HighlightBold
    OptionsRB(matchColor) = NoColor
    OptionsRB(optSelHighlight) =
```

which is strange as it is not showing me the element scrollTree. I don't know if I am missing something. I read about array key issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833306/tcl-array-question-key-with-quotes) but that seems to be the problem with quote so not sure what's missing. Any comments?

Update : I do see onething that is, even though i am assigning the value to this variable in my namespace `set OptionsRB(scrollTree) "LeftTree";` but my `Left Tree` radiobutton is not selected by default, which i think is the cause of error, but then i am not sure why the default radiobutton is not selected.

Comment: I'm not sure yet why the array member isn't there, but the invocation `info exists $OptionsRB(scrollTree)´ is wrong. What you are testing here is whether there exists a variable with a name that is equal to the value of `OptionsRB(scrollTree)`. The invocation should be `info exists OptionsRB(scrollTree)`.

Comment: Thanks Hoodiecrow, i see my mistake. But still i am not sure about the error.

Comment: I've been busy for a couple of hours, but when I tried your code now it worked for me, and the `OptionsRB(scrollTree)` member was present. So I don't really have any clue what your problem is. You do have a misplaced `-yscrollcommand` that shows up when you click one of the radio buttons, however.

Comment: Thanks Hoodie. it seems for some reason the "set OptionsRB(scrollTree) "LeftTree";" was not getting initialized in the namespace declaration. So when i added "set OptionsRB(scrollTree) "LeftTree";" inside the yview procedure in the if condition where it checks for the variable existence, it works fine. So i guess its the initialization issue. Anyways the issue is resolved so thanks for your help.